# How to wait for a jQuery function to finish before moving on?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, forms

So right now I have the code

```
$('[name=dept]').live('change',function() {
$('#course').load('getCla.php?dept='+$(this).val());
$('select.speedC').selectmenu({style:'dropdown',maxHeight: 250}); 
});
```

Basically, what it does is propagate a form select menu after a value is chosen. The problem is, the third line doesn't have its intended action, it it tries to execute before the 2nd line finishes filling the list.

Is there a way to make the 3rd line wait until the list has finished propagating? (As filling the list reformats the list).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the callback parameter of [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/), like this:

```
$('#course').load('getCla.php?dept='+$(this).val(), function() { 
  $('select.speedC').selectmenu({style:'dropdown',maxHeight: 250}); 
});
```

The callback runs when the response comes back and the `#course` element has the new content.  It also receives the returned html from the server as the first argument, if you need it for any reason.

Also since your initial selector is so expensive, I highly recommend [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) here, like this:

```
$('body').delegate('[name=dept]', 'change', function() {
  $('#course').load('getCla.php?dept='+$(this).val(), function() { 
    $('select.speedC').selectmenu({style:'dropdown',maxHeight: 250}); 
  });
});
```

Comment: .. I cant seem to get my answer in before you...always seem to be one step behind.  But I did beat you to this one..  I was actually supprised you did not provide an answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4084095/help-in-jquery-selectors

Comment: @John - probably because I was asleep :) contrary to any rumors, I do sleep around 4-6 hours a day :)

Answer (score 2):

use the call back function in [jQuery load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Like This:

```
$('[name=dept]').live('change',function() {
  $('#course').load('getCla.php?dept='+$(this).val(), function (responseText, textStatus, xhr) {
    $('select.speedC').selectmenu({style:'dropdown',maxHeight: 250}); 
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Nick answered first, so I gotta pick him, but you still helped!